# How to dynamically populate Combobox in Datagridview Column

Tags: c#

I need to populate combobox datasource in a datagridview based on the current row.
Here is my code. I am new to C# so bare with me.

```
public class DrugBrand{
    
    public int id{get;set;}
    public String name{get;set;}//to string override
    public int chemical_id{get;set;}
    
}

IList<DrugBrand> brands=new List<DrugBrand>();
brands.add(new DrugBrand(
  id=1,
  name="Panadol Brand",
  chemical_id=1;
  
){});
brands.add(new DrugBrand(
  id=2,
  name="Cetamol 1 Brand",
  chemical_id=1;
  
){});
brands.add(new DrugBrand(
  id=3,
  name="Cetamol Brand",
  chemical_id=2;
  
){});
public IList<DrugBrand> getBrands(int chemical_id)
{
    return brands.Where(s=>s.chemical_id==chemical_id).ToList();
}

 foreach (PatientDrugPrescriptionEntity e in prescribed_drugs)
            {
                DrugEntity drug = e.drug;


                  //the null value is my combobox column I need to get data source from getBrands(drug.chemical_id);
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(e.id, drug.chemical.name,null, e.notes, e.quantity, e.quantity_bought, e.to_buy, AppUtil.formatCurrency(drug.selling_price),

                "Notes");
                }
```

I have tried to add DisplayMember and ValueMember but does not work